# SQLite column with affinity TEXT still stores long number as INTEGER

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called `deliverysimp` into which I am trying to insert some data. I am aware that the data types for the columns are just affinities and not restrictions, however I need to store the `parcelid` column below as `TEXT`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deliverysimp (parcelid TEXT, expected integer, primary key (parcelid))
```

I am using the following javascript to insert the data to the database:

```
context.executeSql("INSERT INTO deliverysimp(parcelid, expected) values(?,?)",
    [
    '' + delivery.parcelid,
    delivery.expected
    ], function () { }, me.ErrorHandler);
```

You can see I have tried to add a blank `'' +` before the parcelid to try and force the affinity, but the behaviour is the same without; namely:

if I try to store the parcelid `33333333333322222222222222222222223` this is stored into the database as `3.3333333333322223e+34` and I need this to be a text/string representation.

Any ideas how I can get SQLite to honour this as `TEXT`?

Comment: JavaScript is happy to interpret `+` as addition of numbers. Try `toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you already have a string, just not the string you expected.  Since the number you have cannot be represented by an 8-byte integer, it gets converted into a real number and **that** gets converted into a string, i.e., '3.3333333333322223e+34'.  So, if you want the value to be '33333333333322222222222222222222223', then that's what you have to insert into the table.

To check, do a `SELECT parcelid, TYPEOF(parcelid) FROM deliverysimp;` using the `sqlite3` command-line tool and see what you get.

Comment: You were correct. When I went back to the initialisation of the function and checked the parameter being passed in there, the `parcelid` was already set as `3.3333333333322223e+34`, so I needed to find the culprit earlier in the code. Great advice for helping to pinpoint the error, thank you.

Comment: @RussAwesome: Glad to have been of help.